# Does embedding rebars along the face provide tensile strength to a load-bearing wall?

Tags: repair, load-bearing

The house dates back a billion years. Some parts older than others, and added as either obvious/not-so-obvious extension.

One such structure is a stand-alone room whose rear-wall (upto about 3 feet above the ground) are thick stones with what appears to be lime mortar dating goodness knows when. The sides perpendicular to the back wall are (I believe) load bearing (constructed without the aid of concrete pillar/beam) bricks dating to the early 1900s.

Both side-walls have developed a network of deep, through cracks beginning about the same height at the point they join the rear wall. I'm told embedding rebars along the load-bearing wall shall provide the necessary tensile strength.

Does embedding rebars along a load-bearing wall provide some tensile strength to it?

Comment: Tensile strength is the main reason for using rebar, but retrofitting it in a way that makes it effective can get very involved.

Answer (score 1):

I had to read your question a few times, but I still don't know how you intend on reinforcing the walls with rebar.

You cannot simply put rebar against the existing walls and cover them with some mortar.

For rebar to be effective, it must be embedded in the proper thickness and rating of concrete for the load.  the concrete supports the weight and the rebar helps keep the concrete from failing or displacing.  I really think you may need a little on site professional help here. Unless you know how to pour walls, footers etc, you may get in over your head.